# Dictionaries and Lambdas fun

Tags: c#, dictionary, lambda

Why would this compile:

```
public Dictionary<ValueLineType, 
                  Func<HtmlHelper, 
                       string, 
                       object, 
                       Type, 
                       string>> constructor = 
       new Dictionary<ValueLineType, 
                      Func<HtmlHelper, 
                           string, 
                           object, 
                           Type, 
                           string>>();
```

but not this other one with one extra parameter in the Func (the boolean):

```
public Dictionary<ValueLineType, 
                  Func<HtmlHelper, 
                       string, 
                       object, 
                       Type, 
                       bool,  
                       string>> constructor = 
       new Dictionary<ValueLineType, 
                      Func<HtmlHelper, 
                           string, 
                           object, 
                           Type, 
                           bool, 
                           string>>();
```

Either I'm getting blind or there's something else I'm going to learn today :D

Comment: By the way, the error for the second line is: "Using the generic type 'System.Func<T,TResult>' requires '2' type arguments"

Comment: BTW, the 'var' keyword is your new friend. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033#9035.

Comment: definitely much better than writing all that twice!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no such thing as `Func<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,TResult>`. It only goes as far as 4 parameters (i.e. 5 *type* parameters, including one for the return value):

```
Func<T>
Func<T1, TResult>
Func<T1, T2, TResult>
Func<T1, T2, T3, TResult>
Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, TResult>
SpinalTap<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, TResult>
```

You can declare your own, of course:

```
public delegate TResult Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, TResult>
    (T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5);
```

However, at that point I'd think really carefully about whether you might be able to encapsulate some of those parameters together. Are they completely unrelated?

Comment: But there is no reason you couldn't add your own since they are just delegates with generics.

Comment: @Me: Add your own with more than 4 parameters.

Comment: I love the Spinal Tap reference :) + 1

Answer (score 10):

FYI, the next version of the .NET libraries will include Func and Action generic types of more than four parameters.

Answer (score 3):

There are different classes defined by the framework named Func that take from 1 to 5 parameters. You'd need to define your own class that takes 6.

Comment: Func only defines as far as 4 parameters - but 5 *type* parameters.

Answer (score 0):

[Func only](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534303.aspx) takes 4 args, and a TResult